# How to change colors of google calendar based fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Hi i have a google calendar which i am accessing via the Fullcalendar library. The events are diffrently colored on the google calendar but when they are fetched in fullcalendar the color of all events are same. The code for implentation:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fullcalendar.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fullcalendar.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gcal.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },

        displayEventTime: false,
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'API KEY',
        events: {
            googleCalendarId: 'Calendar Id'
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

When the events are fetched into fullcalendar all the events have same color. It would be a great if anyone can help me understand what am I doing wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.